# High school student vs. high-school student

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice, hyphens

I thought high school should have an hyphen in the middle when used as an adjective. Therefore:

> I'm in high school (noun)
>
> I'm a high-school student. (adjective)

But after a [Google Book search](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&hs=AdT&biw=1855&bih=984&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ACYBGNS5r_CzHfqBEzF6DG4j5rprMGKhpw%3A1579421473117&ei=IQ8kXvHlBsiNr7wPleaQuAs&q=%22high-school%20student%22&oq=%22high-school%20student%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...4666.4840.0.5017.2.2.0.0.0.0.40.73.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.EfiE8YWTPqw), I realized that the non-hyphenated version is more common.

Why is this? And when should the hyphenated version be used?

Comment: If you're writing for someone (an editor or a professor), you will likely be given a style manual, which will advise you about hyphenation. Such rules are arbitrary, though rational, and have exceptions. Alas, *whys* are often unanswerable. Perhaps no one is worried that "high school student" means a school student who is high.

Comment: @user105719 I self-publish. So I have to decide my own style.

Comment: I suggest the *Chicago Manual of Style*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using hyphens in compound adjectives, e.g. a two-seater aircraft, a high-school student, a heavy-metal detector, is considered compulsory in British English, but US English is more lenient, and hyphenation is optional except where ambiguity would arise without a hyphen, or where it is desired to help the reader.

> If you're unsure, use a hyphen.

[Hyphens in compound adjectives](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/hyphens_in_compound_adjectives.htm)

[To hyphenate or not to hyphenate?](https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2007/10/to-hyphenate-or-not-to-hyphenate.html)